# Is it possible to use custom deserializer in KSQLDB

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, ksqldb

Is there a way to  configure a custom  avro deserializer in KSQL, without storing schema in schema registry.  I want to store schema  in a file system rather than schema registry.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: This is not possible today, you can up-vote this ticket though: https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/1057

Comment: We want to use AWS Glue schema registry rather than Confluent schema registry